# Symfony passing array using findBy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4 in my project and I'm trying to get the list of users by role which is passed as a query parameter but I'm stuck with the findBy function as I'm trying to pass an array into it

The user entity has a property called roles (code from User.php)

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];
    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    
        return array_unique($roles);
    }
    
    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    
        return $this;
    }
```

The controller :

```php
    public function get_all_users(
        Request $request
    ) {
        if ($request->query->get('role')) {
            $selectedRole = $request->query->get('role');
            $users = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(User::class)
                ->findBy(['roles' => $selectedRole])
                //->findBy(['roles' => ['ROLE_CANDIDATE', 'ROLE_USER']])
                //->findBy(['roles' => ['ROLE_CANDIDATE']])
                //->findBy(['roles' => 'ROLE_CANDIDATE'])
            ;
    
        //->findBy(['roles' => ['ROLE_CANDIDATE', 'ROLE_USER']])
        } else {
            //fetch all users
            $users = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(User::class)
                ->findAll()
        ;
        }
        //Response
        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'Users fetched successfully',
            'users' => $users,
        ], 200, [], ['groups' => 'UserResponse']);
    }
```

the response is always empty when I try to get users by role

this is a screenshot of the table `user` to show how the roles are stored in the database

[image]

Comment: The default Symfony user object 'cheats' by storing roles as a json array.  So you can't query them directly.  You could refactor by creating a Role entity and establishing an association with the User entity.  Or you could do a bit of searching and see how to use the JSON_EXTRACT SQL function.  Bit of a pain.  The easiest way is to just grab all the users and then filter by role though if you have many users it might be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The findBy method use an exact correspondance. Plus your role are json encoded in database. So you could not retrieve your user by role like this.

You will have to use DQL and 'like' condition:

Here is some quick exemple you can use in your User directory if you whish to filter by multiple role. (each user having at list on of these role will be retrieve)

```
/**
 * @return User[]
 */
public function findUserByRole(array $roles): array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user');
    $or = false;
    foreach ($roles as $key => $role) {
        if ($or) {
            $qb->orWhere('user.roles like :role' . $key)
               ->setParameter('role' . $key, '%' . $role . '%');
        } else {
            $qb->where('user.roles like :role' . $key)
               ->setParameter('role' . $key, '%' . $role . '%');
            $or = true;
        }
    }
    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
}
```

change the or by and to match each user having exactly all of these role

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but I think findBy does an exact match. $roles field is Doctrine's simple_array (or json_array, don't remember now) so you will never find by role name

Comment: You only need 50 rep to comment so you might consider avoiding these sorts of 'comment answers'. If you actually know how to solve the problem then by all means post a solution.  Especially if you have a better solution than the various duplicate questions.  But these sorts of 'answers' are just going to get downvoted.

Comment: Isn't it the answer? The guy reports findBy method returning zero results when searching by role. I answer it's not possibile. Done.